# A conceptual explanation for the Kirchoff matrix theorem in terms of the quiver algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, linear-algebra, graph-theory, quivers

On the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem#Explicit_enumeration_of_spanning_trees) page for the Kirchoff matrix theorem, they state a souped up version of the theorem:

Let $G$ be a finite undirected loopless graph and let us form the square matrix $L$ indexed by the vertices of the graph $G$ so that $L_{vv} = \sum_{e = (v,w)}x_e$ and $L_{vw} = -x_{(v,w)}$ where $e = (v,w)$ is an edge between vertices $v,w$ and we have variables $x_e$ for each edge in the graph.

Note that each row and column sum is zero so that each minor of $L$ gotten by deleting one row/column has the same determinant and this determinant turns out to be:
$$\det'(L) = \sum_{T}\prod_{e\in T}x_e$$
where we sum over spanning trees $T$. I can prove this last statement in a hands on way but it seems like it should have a conceptual explanation.

In particular, this reminds me a lot of the [quiver algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quiver_(mathematics)), is there a way to interpret Kirchoff's theorem using quiver algebras (or perhaps the representation theory of some similar ring)?

As an example of what I mean by a conceptual explanation, the [Frobenius determinant theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_determinant_theorem) is along the lines of what I am aiming for. It is a very explicit statement about determinants of some matrix associated to any finite group but secretly, it's a statement about the irreducible representation decomposition of the group algebra $k[G]$. Is there some similar statement here with respect to the ring $k[x_e : e = (v,w)]$?

Comment: There are many known proofs of the Matrix-Tree theorem; I find your description of what qualifies as "conceptual" a little unclear. But for instance determinants are related to volumes, and there are thus connections between the M-T theorem and polyhedral/tropical geometry- see for instance https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.4259.

Comment: @SamHopkins I guess I really do have something fairly concrete in mind by "conceptual" and I edited the question to include this. I would really like an explanation in terms of representations of the ring $k[x_e : e = (v,w)]$ and also perhaps an interpretation of this ring?

Comment: Well the ring $k[x_e]$ knows nothing about the structure of $G$ so I don't see much hope there. (Though somewhat similar, and definitely related to M-T stuff, is the notion of cut and cycle spaces of a graph, which are subspaces of the vs of formal linear combinations of edges.) Whether there is any connection between path algebras of a quiver and the M-T theorem is a quite interesting question, I have no idea about that...

Comment: Right, we would definitely like to impose more structure on $k[x_e]$ before trying to use it - I am just not sure what structure to impose.

Comment: One more possible place to look for associating an algebraic structure to a graph and getting the M-T theorem out of it: in https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.1148 it is explained how to obtain the chromatic polynomial of a graph from its associated Kac-Moody algebra. Now, the chromatic polynomial does not contain knowledge of the number of spanning trees- but the closely related Tutte polynomial does. And, even if we could get to number of spanning trees this way, not clear at all where a determinant would come in. But again, it's along the lines of what you were inquiring about...

Comment: That is interesting, thank you!